# Get request on real device Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, get, request

The iPhone emulator receives data when a request is received, but the physical device does not, can someone tell me what the problem might be?

```
public List<Photo> GetPhotoSearch(double northEastLatitude, double northEastLongtitude,
                                          double southWestLatitude, double southWestLongtitude)
        {
            List<Photo> photos = new List<Photo>();

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($"{totalUrl}/northEast='{northEastLatitude}'-'{northEastLongtitude}'" +
                                                   $"_southWest='{southWestLatitude}'-'{southWestLongtitude}'");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        photos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Photo>>(line);
                    }
                }
            }
  
            response.Close();

            return photos;
        }
```

Comment: what happens on a "real" device?  Do you get an error or exception?  Is it timing out?  Have you verified that your device has connectivity to your server?

Comment: @Jason there are no errors or exceptions on the device. There are also no problems with the server, since everything else in the application works fine the same way with it, even the device. But this part works fine only on the emulator, but not on the device.

Comment: So there are other services that the device CAN connect to?  And this particular call does connect but does not receive any data?  Have you checked the server logs, or debugged the server endpoint, to see what happens when the request is received?

Comment: @Jason For now I am the only one who is connected to the server. I meant that all other requests also go to this server and work correctly both on the emulator and on the device. I checked the logs on the server - everything is also correct. When the request is received, it simply does not contain any data (if it is on the emulator, it contains list of objects)

Comment: Does the server require the credentials? If so, please set the credentials. `WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` And you could try using HttpClient to achieve the function: `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);`.